# Jasny off canvas menu reappears when closed

Tags: jasny-bootstrap

I'm using the jasny offcanvas menu which works well but strangely, when I open and then close the menu, it slides out and then reappears. I assuming this is a z-index issue or maybe an HTML structure problem, but I can't see it.

Current development site is at http://powerdirect.petersenuploads.co.uk/, shrink the window to <768px to see the effect.

What am I missing here?

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: The link isn't working. Please create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Hi Arnold, I fixed this by overriding a display:block. It looked like the javascript was hiding it again.